# Ads for Stackoverflow careers illegible/poorly rendered

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, advertising

Not sure is this has been reported before - I searched and couldn't find anything...

On the StackOverflow site I see ads for StackOverflow Careers.  But the image and the text in theses ads are superimposed and it makes it difficult to read.

This happens on my work laptop running IE7 on XP and on IE7 on Win2003.
I don't remember seeing this on my home PC (IE8 on Win7).

[image]

Comment: It's hinting you to dump IE7 :P

Comment: Possibly so, but I can't change my corporate desktop :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, It's an IE7 issue. We'll fix, thanks for letting us know.